# Detect Date and time changed in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I would detect in my application when the user change date or time
I modify my manifest in order to catch the action android.intent.action.TIME_SET with a BroadcastReceiver
it works Fine

But in my application, I set the date and time when the phone is connected to a WIFI network and connected to our servers
I manage this with this code :

```
try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
                process.getOutputStream());

        os.writeBytes("date -s " + datetime + "\n");
        os.writeBytes("exit\n");
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        // on récupère l'inputStream sinon on a un deadLock pour le process
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        /*
         * //on récupère l'errorStream sinon on a un deadLock pour le
         * process BufferedReader errorProcess = new BufferedReader(new
         * InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream())); while ((line =
         * errorProcess.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println(line); }
         */
        /*
         * if(ir == null) ir = new InterventionRepository(this); ir.Open();
         * ir.purgeMensuelle(); ir.Close();
         */
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } finally {
        if (process != null)
            process.destroy();
    }
```

this code triggers the action too

How can I differenciate, the date and time change by my code, and the date and time change in the preferences

I have a BroadcastReceiver like this :

```
package com.onyx.telegestion;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class TimeChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String TIMECHANGEDTAG = "TIMECHANGEDTAG"; 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.i(TIMECHANGEDTAG,this.toString());
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.i(TIMECHANGEDTAG, "Date changée : "+cal.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class DateTimeChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED) || action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED))) {
            boolean isAutoDateTimeEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1;
            if (isAutoDateTimeEnabled) {
                Log.d("DateTimeChangeReceiver", "Automatic date and time is enabled");
            } else {
                Log.d("DateTimeChangeReceiver", "Automatic date and time is disabled");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_CHANGED" />
```